# How to select multiple item from list with related condition

Tags: c#, linq, select

So I have a class:

```
public class Timing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Duration { get; set; }
}
```

And a list of the Timing class:

```
List<Timing> times = GetTimings();
```

So I want to select `t1` and `t2` from `times` where `t1.Duration + t2.Duration == 20;` How could I select both items together with this condition? any idea?

Comment: Where is `t2` coming from?

Comment: Can t1 and t2 be the same Timing instance?

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, t1 and t2 are different instances

Comment: @Saeid: Ok, is it allowed to have t1 + t2 and also t2 + t1? You can always reverse the combination of two different timing instances which sum of duration is 20.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes it is allowed, I am not sure understand your mean. but I just want two paired of Timinig instance with sum of 20

Comment: Yes. But if one instance with id=1 has duration=5 and another id=2, duration=15, do you want a list which contains 1 pair or 2 pairs? So 1/2 alone or 1/2 and 2/1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with LINQ by performing a self-join, but the algorithm would be O(n<sup>2</sup>) due to filtering a Cartesian product.

You can do it a lot faster - in O(n), if you construct a dictionary mapping a duration to a list of `Timing` objects that correspond to that duration, and then retrieving lists from the dictionary for `20 - t.Duration`:

```
var byDuration = times.GroupBy(t => t.Duration).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
var pairs = new List<Tuple<Timing,Timing>>();
foreach (var t1 in times) {
    List<Timing> list;
    if (byDuration.TryGetValue(20-t1.Duration, out list)) {
        pairs.AddRange(list.Where(t2 => t1 != t2).Select(t2 => Tuple.Create(t1, t2)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
var query= from t1 in times
           from t2 in times
           where t1!=t2 && (t1.Duration + t2.Duration) == 20
           select new {t1,t2};
```

In case you want to do it without repetitions:

```
var query = from index in Enumerable.Range(0, times.Count)
            let t1= times[index] 
            from t2 in times.Skip(index + 1)
            where (t1.Duration + t2.Duration) == 20
            select new { t1, t2};
```